# php form - purpose of printing the value of a variable?

Tags: php, forms

I've got another theory question. Sorry if these seem dumb but I'm trying to get a better understanding of how things works.

In forms what is the purpose of printing a variable? I tested a form and the data is written when omitting the value tag so what does it do?!! Is it necessary? I have validation running in the form and that also executes without the value tag.

```
<input id="name" type="text" value="<?PHP print $name ; ?>"/>
```

Comment: If you need to repopulate your form this is the only way to do it.

Comment: Or enter a default value.

Comment: ...that's where a ternary operator comes in handy. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value attribute provides a default value, which will usually either be:

- A sensible default (e.g. "Tomorrow at 9am" for a calendar) *or*
- Whatever the user entered last time when there was something wrong with the overall submission (so they don't need to retype the whole form)

Using a variable means you don't have to hard code it.